# Different data types in nested dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

FYI: New to Swift, mainly coming from the world of Python.

I'm trying to understand dictionaries in Swift. As dictionaries are type safe in Swift I wonder why I can have nested dictionaries with different data types. I've been experimenting in XCode Playground. Example follows:

```
let dict = ["country": "France"]
```

works fine as it is `[String: String]` data type.

I also kind of understand the following one (is it `[String: [String: String]]`?):

```
let dict2 = [
  "France": [
    "capital": "Paris",
    "anthem": "La Marseillaise"],
  "Germany": [
    "capital": "Berlin",
    "anthem": "Das Lied der Deutschen"]
]
```

However I don't understand the following one. Why can the nested dictionary contain different data types (e.g. strings and integers)?

```
let dict3 = [
  "France": [
    "capital": "Paris",
    "anthem": "La Marseillaise",
    "population": 67_390_000],
  "Germany": [
    "capital": "Berlin",
    "anthem": "Das Lied der Deutschen",
    "population": 83_240_000]
]
```

Then I try to read the values and I can only read "the first level", i.e. `dict2["France"]`, but not e.g. `dict2["France"]["anthem"]`. How come I can't read from the nested dictionary? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Make a class/struct. Using dictionaries in this way is very inconvenient in Swift, unlike in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something fundamental here?

You are.

A dictionary containing multiple heterogenous values is `[String:Any]`. The compiler cannot infer the type, it suggests to annotate it

> ❗️Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional.

By the way there are some syntax mistakes in your code.

```
let dict : [String:[String:Any]] = [
  "France": [
    "capital": "Paris",
    "anthem": "La Marseillaise",
    "population": 67_390_000],
  "Germany": [
    "capital": "Berlin",
    "anthem": "Das Lied der Deutschen",
    "population": 83_240_000]
]
```

To read the value again the compiler doesn't know the static type represented by `Any`, you have to downcast the type.

This is the safe way to get the anthem, as dictionary keys can be missing an optional is returned which must be (safely) unwrapped

```
if let france = dict["France"], // no cast is needed because the compiler knows it's a dictionary
   let marseillaise = france["anthem"] as? String {
    print(marseillaise)
}
```

---

The type safer *swiftier* way is a custom struct

```
struct Country {
    let capital, anthem: String
    let population: Int
}

let dict = [
  "France": Country(capital: "Paris", anthem: "La Marseillaise", population: 67_390_000),
  "Germany": Country(capital: "Berlin", anthem: "Das Lied der Deutschen", population: 83_240_000)
]
```

Now the compiler can infer the type `[String:Country]`, however you still have to safely unwrap the optional, but no type cast/annotation is required at all.

```
if let france = dict["France"] {
    print(france.anthem)
}
```

Comment: The [String:Any] possibility seems a bit like a deviation from being type safe though.  Is it a rare exception? Thanks for both explanation and improvement suggestion.

Comment: `Any` is the compromise to represent *any* type even in a heterogenous collection type. The type safety appears at the moment the compiler forces you to specify the proper concrete type (`as? String` in the dictionary example).

Answer (score 1):

When you make `dict3` as

```
let dict3:[String:Any] = [
    "France": [   //key is a String 
      "capital": "Paris",
      "anthem": "La Marseillaise",   // it's values are [String:Any] as 67_390_000 is integer and La Marseillaise & Paris are  strings 
      "population": 67_390_000
    ],
    "Germany": [  //key is a String 
      "capital": "Berlin",   
      "anthem": "Das Lied der Deutschen",   // it's values are [String:Any] as 83_240_000 is integer and 83_240_000 & Berlin  are strings
      "population": 83_240_000
    ]
  ]
```

it's inferred type is `[String:Any]/[String:[String:Any]]` so you need a cast

```
 if let france = dict3["France"] as? [String:Any] , let anthem =  france["anthem"] as? String {
     print(anthem)
 }
```